# Azure Performance Metrics Portal monitor value is different when using Get-AzMetric Powershell script output

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line

does anyone can explain why there is a discrepancy in the Output of the Powershell script when I used Get-AzMetric command in obtaining the data from the Azure Performance Metrics Portal?

This is the value from Azure Portal Performance Metric:
[Azure Portal Value][image]

Powershell Script:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***To get appropriate results, you need to modify the Time Granularity and Interval accordingly. Below are two scenarios where I have changed the time granularity and verified the metrics.***

***Case1***: ***Set the time granularity to 00:01:00***

```
$cpu = Get-AZmetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Identity-Resources/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vmname>"-TimeGrain 00:01:00 -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -Detailedoutput
$CPU.data
```

***Snapshot:***

[image]

***Case2***: ***Set the time granularity to 00:15:00, which is the case you are testing too.***

```
$cpu = Get-AZmetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/Identity-Resources/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<vmname>"-TimeGrain 00:15:00 -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -Detailedoutput
$CPU.data
```

Make sure to change Time granularity and show time accordingly like below:

[image]